# UIButton auto-adjust Button font size Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I try to make out some quiz and have a problem with my answer buttons. 
Simple fact: The text is too long and I try to auto-adjust it for cells using different methods. My current status:

```
        for btn in btnArr{
        btn.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3
        btn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btn.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters
        //btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3.0,left: 3.0,bottom: 3.0,right: 3.0)
    }
```

I hope somebody has another option for me to make that work :)

Regards,
Patrick

EDIT:

```
 self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn.titleLabel!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: btn, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.99, constant: 0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With auto layout you can set the space between buttons, and the max and min size. In code for all labels use:

```
self.button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

With this all labels adjust the text will size.

For adjust button to titleLabel use auto layout constraint for titleLabel. For examples:

```
  [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button.titleLabel
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:0.5
                                                           constant:0]];
```

This constraint define the height of titleLabel to 50% of `self.view` height. Now you can adapte the constraint for that you need.

This work in you code?

Comment: as you can see in my code example that doesn't work for my Buttons[!]

Comment: For this code I use Label. In your application you can try remove the buttons and use the labels.

Comment: I refer the instruction to "btn.titleLabel" so it's also working with a label. But as you see on the screenshot above it doesn't work... :(

Comment: The problem is the on button. Your `btn.titleLabel` really adjust to the text but the button not adjust to the `titleLabel`.  You understand?

Comment: And there is no way to make the label fit the button?

Comment: First: Thank you very much for taking your time!
Second: No it doesn't work really right.
I updated my question with the new version.

But now it shows 3 (fitting) lines but deletes the rest of the title...

Comment: Try see my [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlrexaijapyvnu8/tabbar.zip?dl=0) I hope it can help you.

If don't work try use labels

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it doesn't work for me because i have lots of other constraints and your solution destroys them. But for other people it will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cells are to be of same height with same font, you can restrict the text by setting the "numberOfLines" to a value other than 0 (like 3 or 4).

Comment: That just cuts the part of the String which is too long, so thats not an option :(